# How to post a message in chatter during create method in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I was writing create method for my own custom module.

```
def create(self, cr, uid,ids, context=None):
        self.message_post(cr, uid, ids, body=_("Form Page created"), context=None)
```

but i am getting the following error when saving
AssertionError: Invalid thread_id; should be 0, False, an ID or a list with one ID

or sometimes

TypeError: create() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context'

i just want to post a message when it is created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Openerp 7 Create Method**

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
     new_id = super(CRM_Lead, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
     return new_id
```

**odoo 8 Create Method:**

class ClassName(models.Model):
    _inherit = "model.name"

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    rec = super(ClassName, self).create(vals)
    # ...        
    return rec
```

Make sure you use the exact name of the python class in the super function and also that you return the same object you get from it.

**Track Visibility**

You can set a mail.message.subtype that depends on an other to act through a relation field.

For better understanding track visibilty Refer [This Link](https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/help-1/question/use-of-track-and-track-visibility-10363)

There is two type fileds of track visibility

```
track_visibility='always' 
track_visibility='onchange'
```